# Change Text for NavigationController back button with TableView Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegation

I'm trying to change the text that follows the < on the Navigation Controller. I successfully accomplished this in a UIViewController with a TableView that is its own DataSource and Delegate with code like this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var newVC = NewViewController()
    self.title = "HomeVC"
    navigationController?.showViewController(newVC, sender: indexPath)
}
```

When "HomeViewController" is presented, the back button on the Navigation Controller shows "< HomeVC" - the ViewController that we just came from.

Now, I'm trying to accomplish this with another UIViewController that has a TableView, but the DataSource and Delegate are in a separate file. Following the same logic as above, this is what I tried:

```
 class CalendarTableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
     ...
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var newVC = NewViewController()
        self.navController?.title = "HomeVC"  // ----> did not work
        HomeViewController().title = "HomeVC"    // ----> did not work
        self.navController?.showViewController(newVC, sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Ideas, anyone? Assuming that I want to keep the DataSource and Delegate in a separate file.

Comment: The "same logic as above" (i.e. `self.title = "Home"`) would be `self.title = "NewVC"`.

Comment: I tried that too. But because this is not a UIViewController, there is no "self.title"

Comment: But then what do you mean by this: "I'm trying to accomplish this with another UIViewController that has a TableView"? So it isn't a UIViewController after all?

Comment: `NewViewController.title = "NewVC"` should be `newVC.title = "NewVC"`.

Comment: @LyndseyScott - yes, I am trying to do this with another UIViewController, but the TableView Delegate, which has the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method, which is what performs the segue, is in a separate file.

Comment: @neugierige Then instead of accessing the title property of "self", you should be accessing the title property of "whateverThatOtherUIViewControllerIs".

Comment: @LyndseyScott - I've edited my question for better clarity. I think the suggestion you made is what I tried to do with "HomeViewController().title = "HomeVC" - but this did not work either.

Comment: @neugierige that wouldn't work because you're creating a brand new instance of HomeViewController when you instead need to access the current instance.

Comment: @LyndseyScott - that makes sense...but how do I do that?

Comment: @neugierige Really depends on the specifics of how you've set up your program structure, but you should be able to pass in an instance of your UIViewController to the class handling your tableview whenever you create it.